# Pause and unpause a refresh_div by using a button

Tags: javascript

I currently have a chat refreshing every two second, I'd like a button that will pause the script from reloading until they press another or the same button. (PAUSE/UNPAUSE)

```
<div class="chatload">
    <center>LOADING COMMUNITY CHAT</center>
    <script>
       function refresh_div() {
          jQuery.ajax({
             url:'chat.php',
             type:'POST',
             success:function(results) {
                jQuery(".chatload").html(results);
             }
          });
       }

       t = setInterval(refresh_div,2000);
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clear interval to stop/pause it and reassign to start again. here is the example code for that.

**HTML**

```
<button id="togglebtn" type="button" onclick="toggleRefresh();">Pause/Resume Chat</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...
    ...
    var t = setInterval(refresh_div,2000);
    function toggleRefresh(){
        var btn = document.getElementById('togglebtn');
        if(t!=null){
            clearInterval(t);
            t = null;
            btn.innerHTML = "Resume Chat";
        }else{
            t = setInterval(refresh_div,2000);
            btn.innerHTML = "Pause Chat";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, Any chance of having the code to change button state from Pause chat to Resume chat and so on in sync with the javascript given above?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
var isCanceled = false;
function refresh_div() {
  if(!isCanceled) {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url:'chat.php',
      type:'POST',
      success:function(results) {
        jQuery(".chatload").html(results);
      }
    });
  }
}

t = setInterval(refresh_div,2000);

$('a.pause').click(function(){
  isCanceled = !isCanceled;
});
```